# Stop MSBuild from using App.config in .NET6 leg of multitargeted project

Tags: .net, .net-core, msbuild

### Problem:

We have a project that's multitargeted for `net472;net6.0`.

In the `net472` leg it uses an `App.config` (present in project's root) for configuring various settings (GCHeapCount, locks in traces, min supported runtime, GC). And it works great, the `App.config` gets automatically copied to output as `<projectName>.exe.config`, and is then automatically loaded when the app is started.

The issue is with the `net6.0` leg. Obviously, we don't want to re-use the same `App.config` for that compilation. Mainly, because the supported runtime present in the `App.config` is wrong; secondly because we want to configure the GC differently, etc.

But, regrettably, it seems that msbuild/roslyn (not sure who) still takes the `App.config`, copies it to output as `<projectName>.exe.config`; and when the dll is started - the config is loaded (on `ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem`) which doesn't really work since e.g. the system.diagnostics trace settings are not recognizable.

#### Desired state:

Ideally, I'd like to have the `net472` leg without many changes and have the `net6.0` leg simply ignore the `App.config` file, i.e. so that it doesn't even get copied to output folder for that compilation.

### Tried:

I've searched for a way to do it.

Bing chat hallucinated an answer that doesn't work (sign of times?), google was mainly about `App.config` being unintentionally ignored, and the only close things I found was: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs-always-copies-all-appconfig-files-to-output-fol/19696 which, however, only contains workaround for publishing; nothing for just compilation.

I've also tried the trick with:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="App.config" />
    <None Include="App.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

but that also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the app.config support is in `Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets` which is distributed with the SDK.

The [`FindAppConfigFile` task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/findappconfigfile-task?view=vs-2022) is used with `None` as the primary list and `Content` as the secondary. A property named `AppConfig` is set with the path and name of the file. If the `AppConfig` property already has a value the `FindAppConfigFile` task is not invoked.

You might try the following:

```xml
  <ItemGroup  Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0'">
    <None Remove="App.config" />
    <Content Remove="App.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

This should ensure that for the `net6.0` leg, the file is ignored.

If there is ever a need for a `net6.0` specific app.config, you can give the file any name and set the `AppConfig` property, e.g.:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup  Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0'">
    <AppConfig>config.net6</AppConfig>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Regardless of the name of the source file, the generated config file name will be `$(TargetFileName).config`.